# Look up iOS string localization

Tags: swift, localization

Normally I just use NSLocalizedString to handle my translations, but I've got a case where the "key" is stored in a string itself, so I want to look up the localization for that.  I can't remember which method I can call for that.

Comment: You use `NSLocalizedString`. Is this a trick question? Perhaps you should update your question with a concrete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: There used to be some other method you called if you had the string as a variable instead of the concrete text I though. Maybe I’m just remembering wrong.

Comment: In Objective-C, the `NSLocalizedString...` "functions" are really just macros that call the `localizedStringForKey:value:table:` method of `NSBundle`. The Swift `NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)` function's implementation may do the same.